# MyBatis hangs when inserting

Tags: mybatis, spring-mybatis

I am trying to insert a record into Oracle 11g database using MyBatis-Spring, but the insert hangs. Select works fine.

I need another set of eyes to help me figure out what is going on.

Here are the snippets of codes that matter:

**Logging output: (it hangs forever on the last line)**

```
Running persistence.PartyMapperUnitTest
DEBUG [main] - Cache Hit Ratio [persistence.mapper.PartyMapper]: 0.0
DEBUG [main] - ==>  Preparing: SELECT PARTY_ID, PARTY_SUBTYPE_CD, LIFECYCLE_CD, PARTY_STATUS_CD FROM PARTY WHERE PARTY_ID =2 
DEBUG [main] - ==> Parameters: 
DEBUG [main] - <==      Total: 1
DEBUG [main] - ==>  Preparing: INSERT INTO PARTY (PARTY_SUBTYPE_CD, LIFECYCLE_CD, PARTY_STATUS_CD, CREATED_BY) VALUES (?,?,?,?) 
DEBUG [main] - ==> Parameters: partySubtypeCode1438810529048(String), lifecycleCode(String), partyStatusCode(String), createdBy(String)
***==== The application hangs forever at this log line ====***
```

**Testing.sql** (this works fine)

```
INSERT INTO PARTY (PARTY_SUBTYPE_CD, LIFECYCLE_CD, PARTY_STATUS_CD, CREATED_BY)
VALUES ( 'a', 'b', 'c', 'd');
```

**applicationContext.xml**

```
<bean id="transactionManager" class="org.springframework.jdbc.datasource.DataSourceTransactionManager">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>
<bean id="sqlSessionFactory" class="org.mybatis.spring.SqlSessionFactoryBean">
    <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" />
</bean>
```

**PartyMapper.java**

```
public interface PartyMapper<PartyEntity> {
    public PartyEntity fetch(Object entityId);
    public int insert(PartyEntity entity);
}
```

**PartyMapper.xml**

```
<insert
    id="insert"
    parameterType="persistence.entity.PartyEntity"
    keyProperty="partyId"
    keyColumn="PARTY_ID"
    useGeneratedKeys="true">
    INSERT INTO PARTY
        (PARTY_SUBTYPE_CD, LIFECYCLE_CD, PARTY_STATUS_CD, CREATED_BY)
    VALUES
        (#{partySubtypeCode},#{lifecycleCode},#{partyStatusCode},#{createdBy})
</insert>
```

**PartyMapperUnitTest.java**

```
PartyEntity expectedParty = new PartyEntity();
expectedParty.setPartySubtypeCode("a");
expectedParty.setLifecycleCode("b");
expectedParty.setPartyStatusCode("c");
expectedParty.setCreatedBy("d");
partyMapper.insert(expectedParty);
```

**=== EDIT ===**
There are only two threads running when the UnitTest runs. I don't see anything wrong in here.

Added a Thread.dumpStack() before the insert, but did not see anything wrong with it:

**Thread.dumpStack()**

```
INFO: Pre-instantiating singletons in org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@77ab3f0: defining beans [transactionManager,org.springframework.aop.config.internalAutoProxyCreator,org.springframework.transaction.annotation.AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource#0,org.springframework.transaction.interceptor.TransactionInterceptor#0,org.springframework.transaction.config.internalTransactionAdvisor,sqlSessionFactory,dataSource,org.mybatis.spring.mapper.MapperScannerConfigurer#0,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalConfigurationAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalAutowiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalRequiredAnnotationProcessor,org.springframework.context.annotation.internalCommonAnnotationProcessor,mapper,partyMapper,org.springframework.context.annotation.ConfigurationClassPostProcessor$ImportAwareBeanPostProcessor#0]; root of factory hierarchy
java.lang.Exception: Stack trace
    at java.lang.Thread.dumpStack(Thread.java:1365)
    at td.com.naccms.cps.persistence.PartyMapperUnitTest.insert(PartyMapperUnitTest.java:48)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:606)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:45)
...
...
```

Comment: How many connections do you have in your connection pool? I've seen this happen *often* when the DB pool has 1 connection and there are 2 concurrent transactions (so MyBatis cannot get a DB connection, and the jdbc connection pool is the one actually hanging). You can debug your app and 'pause' it when it hangs. You should be able to see the threads and trace which one id blocked and where. Another option, but more rare, is that the table is locked. You can google for some queries that will show you all the current locks in your DB.

Comment: @Augusto, I looked at the threads but I did not see anything unusual with it. Even added a Thread.dumpStack() before the insert and it looks alright to me. By the way, I am using MyBatis-Spring.

Comment: @Augusto it was a database issue, connections were hung in there, we restarted the database and everything worked... what worries me is that it is a silent issue and hard to determine the root cause. You are correct, please re-write your comment as an answer so I can mark as correctly answered.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How many connections do you have in your connection pool? I've seen this happen often when the DB pool has 1 connection and there are 2 concurrent transactions (so MyBatis cannot get a DB connection, and the jdbc connection pool is the one actually hanging). You can debug your app and 'pause' it when it hangs. You should be able to see the threads and trace which one id blocked and where. Another option, but more rare, is that the table is locked. You can google for some queries that will show you all the current locks in your DB.

### edit after your comment

To get a proper error when this happens, my suggestion is to set the [defaultStatementTimeout](https://mybatis.github.io/mybatis-3/configuration.html) in mybatis. This, at least, will throw an exception, rather than hang forever.

You also might want to configure some timeouts in your database connection pool too, as some pools wait forever by default (and that's a loooong time :).

Comment: @YoriKusanagi I strongly suggest you to read a book called [Release It!](https://pragprog.com/book/mnee/release-it). It has a **ton** of good advise about how to design applications to deal with unforeseen errors (such as the one you described above, where the DB hanged when you tried to connect).